# Eureka Server Cache Refresh

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

There are two eureka servers (say ES1 and ES2) with below configuration.

```
spring:
  profiles: production

server:
  port: 8761    

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.peer.hostname}:8761/eureka/
```

The synch works but during release to production when one eureka server(say ES2) is brought down the other eureka server (ES1) still maintains the old cache information and when ES2 is started back it registers the eureka clients but de-registration of old clients doesn't happen which results in stale information used by ribbon load balancer.

For registering eureka clients below configuration is used.

```
eureka:
  instance:
    metadataMap:
      instanceId: ${service.contextPath}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Why old instances are not getting de-registered from eureka server? Because of this we have to do complete shutdown and restart of our infrastructure.

Comment: Hope this helps - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/373#issuecomment-110331739

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you see is the result of Eureka's self preservation feature. In short, an Eureka server automatically stops expiring instance leases when it notices it has received less than 80% of the expected renewals during the last minute. When ES1 goes down, ES2 doesn't receive heartbeats from clients that were originally registered with ES1 anymore - it is then likely to activate the self preservation mode.

To avoid that situation, you should configure your clients with both ES1 *and* ES2: the client will automatically switch to ES2 if ES1 is unavailable. For this, simply list both addresses as follows:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://ES1:8761/eureka/,http://ES2:8761/eureka/
```

You could also disable the self protection feature - but this is not the expected configuration when in cluster - so expect strange behavior :-(

Comment: @Vibhaanshu any news on this? Does the above analysis match what your case?

Comment: Sorry for being late. I noticed that the deployment strategy which was followed was not right. We were not letting the services de-register properly from eureka, because of this peer eureka server has stale service instance ids. The structure what we have is services on one server register with eureka server running on the same server and services one other register with eureka server on that server. Synch happens between the two eureka server. Will test your approach and also in process of defining strategy to deploy services with different versions without any downtime.